# Update retention on existing partitioned table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a DAY partitioned table on BigQuery which did not have any retention set.
I updated the retention now to 48 hours:

```
bq update --time_partitioning_expiration=172800 maw.rt_content_secondly_0
```

And now

```
bq show --format=prettyjson maw.rt_content_secondly_0
```

shows:

```
"timePartitioning": {
"expirationMs": "172800000", 
"type": "DAY"
}
```

But it has been about and hour since I updated and it is still not deleting older data. The `count(*)` is still the same.

Also, how do you remove the retention later if I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38753305/7376017

You can verify the partitions time by looking at:

```
SELECT MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(creation_time) from [project:dataset.table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

Comment: To remove the retention, just set time_partitioning_expiration to a negative number, like 01. From "bq help update":

  --time_partitioning_expiration: Enables time based partitioning on the table and set the number of
    seconds for which to keep the storage for a partition. The storage will have an expiration time of
    its creation time plus this value. A negative number means no expiration.
    (an integer)